# Angular 2 DataService in TypeScript for ASP.NET 5 not displaying data

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-services

This displays Hello World successfully so app.component.ts is bootstrapping correctly. Either no data returned from the DataService or it can't be displayed. There are no compiler errors. Is there a popup window in TypeScript like alert() in JavaScript that I could quickly check to see if data is being returned by the DataService?

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({ 
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<h1>Hello World</h1>
<li *ngFor="#customer of customers">
  <span>{{customer.firstName}}</span> 
</li>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
    public dataService: DataService;
    customers: any[];
    constructor() { }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.getCustomers()
            .subscribe((customers: any[]) => {
                this.customers = customers;
            });
    }
}
```

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http, Response } from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    public http: Http
    constructor() { }

    getCustomers() {
        return this.http.get('customers.json')
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
}
```

Comment: alert works the same in typescript as in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the **DataService** as one of the providers for the component.

```js
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({ 
  selector: 'app',
  providers: [DataService], 
  template: `<h1>Hello World</h1>
<li *ngFor="#customer of customers">
  <span>{{customer.firstName}}</span> 
</li>
`
})
export class AppComponent {

    customers: any[];

    constructor(public dataService: DataService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.getCustomers()
            .subscribe((customers: any[]) => {
                this.customers = customers;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks toskv, I've registered the DataService now however it still isn't working.

Comment: Try injecting the DataService in the constructor, or decorate it with the Inject decoration

Answer (score 2):

With Angular 2 Beta 1 I needed to add bindings instead of a provider and inject the DataService into the Constructor.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Inject, Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { HTTP_BINDINGS } from 'angular2/http';

@Component({ 
    selector: 'app',
    bindings: [DataService, HTTP_BINDINGS],
    template: `<h1>Hello World</h1>
<li *ngFor="#customer of customers">
  <span>{{customer.firstName}}</span> 
</li>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
    private customers: any[];
    constructor( @Inject(DataService) public dataService: DataService) {
        this.dataService = dataService;
    }


    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.getCustomers()
            .subscribe((customers: any[]) => {
                this.customers = customers;
            }); 
    }
}
```